# Hive TABLESAMPLE on clustered table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I want to ask the correct bucketing and tablesample way.

There is a table X which I created by

```
CREATE TABLE `X`(`action_id` string,`classifier` string)
CLUSTERED BY (action_id,classifier) INTO 256 BUCKETS
STORED AS ORC
```

Then I inserted 500M of rows into X by

```
set hive.enforce.bucketing=true;
INSERT OVERWRITE INTO X SELECT * FROM X_RAW
```

Then I want to count or search some rows with condition. roughly,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM X WHERE action_id='aaa' AND classifier='bbb'
```

But I'd better to USE tablesample as I clustered X (action_id, classifier).
So, the better query will be

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM X 
TABLESAMPLE(BUCKET 1 OUT OF 256 ON  action_id, classifier)
WHERE action_id='aaa' AND classifier='bbb'
```

Is there any wrong above?
But I can't not find any performance gain between these two query.

query1 and RESULT( with no tablesample.)

```
SELECT COUNT(*)) from X 
WHERE action_id='aaa' and classifier='bbb'

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        VERTICES      STATUS  TOTAL  COMPLETED  RUNNING  PENDING  FAILED  KILLED
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Map 1 ..........   SUCCEEDED    256        256        0        0       0       0
Reducer 2 ......   SUCCEEDED      1          1        0        0       0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VERTICES: 02/02  [==========================>>] 100%  ELAPSED TIME: 15.35 s    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
It scans full data.
```

query 2 and RESULT

```
SELECT COUNT(*)) from X 
TABLESAMPLE(BUCKET 1 OUT OF 256 ON  action_id, classifier)
WHERE action_id='aaa' and classifier='bbb'

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        VERTICES      STATUS  TOTAL  COMPLETED  RUNNING  PENDING  FAILED  KILLED
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Map 1 ..........   SUCCEEDED    256        256        0        0       0       0
Reducer 2 ......   SUCCEEDED      1          1        0        0       0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VERTICES: 02/02  [==========================>>] 100%  ELAPSED TIME: 15.82     s    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
It ALSO scans full data.
```

query 2 RESULT WHAT I EXPECTED.

```
Result what I expected is something like...
(use 1 map and relatively faster than without tabmesample)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        VERTICES      STATUS  TOTAL  COMPLETED  RUNNING  PENDING  FAILED  KILLED
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Map 1 ..........   SUCCEEDED      1          1        0        0       0       0
Reducer 2 ......   SUCCEEDED      1          1        0        0       0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VERTICES: 02/02  [==========================>>] 100%  ELAPSED TIME: 3.xx     s    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Values of action_id and classifier are well distributed and there is no skewed data.

So I want to ask you what will be a correct query to target Only 1 Bucket and Use 1 map??

Comment: so what is the count you got both the times and also what is the hdfs read in both cases? could not figure out.

Comment: please refer to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-13766  . It seems  there exist underlying bug about hash clustering.